# select records not in other selection of records

Tags: mysql

this query returns empty set !

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE Sid='1' AND Bid='0' AND
NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Sid='1' AND Bid='1')
```

Bid   Sid  Name

0     1    A

0     1    B

1     1    A

I want the records not in this sub-query

```
  SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Sid='1' AND Bid='1'
```

so what should I use ??

Comment: What do you want to get here?

Comment: Subquery `SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Sid='1' AND Bid='1'` will always return one tuple, so `NOT EXISTS` condition will always be false and you will always get empty result

Comment: @AndreiShender I want the records not in this subquery  
     (SELECT Name FROM category WHERE Sid='1' AND Bid='1')
so what should I use ??

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell what is it exactly you want since you didn't post the desired output, but looking at conditions in your `NOT EXISTS` clause I assume that you might want to exclude from output all records that have `Sid='1' AND Bid='1'`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM category 
 WHERE Sid <> 1 
    OR Bid <> 1
```

Sample output:

```
| BID | SID | NAME |
--------------------
|   0 |   1 |    A |
|   0 |   1 |    B |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb91c/1)** demo

*If it's not the case just edit your question and add desired output from the query based on your sample data*